# google_mlkit_translation. More words translated

Tags: flutter, dart, translation, google-mlkit

I am using google_mlkit_translation in my application. I want to translate one word at a time. Is it possible to get more than one translation at a time? I have searched many threads, but I have not found an answer anywhere.

Get more than one translation at a time in google_mlkit_translation